# Bash command find with exec and grep not working properly, anything wrong?

Tags: bash, centos, find

I want to filter my log files with the keyword ALARM/FATAL in lines into another backup files, suppose I have the following two files

```
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat test_ccd.log 
ccd0.log:01-28 09:33:18:461 1254 F NORMAL
ccd0.log:01-28 09:33:18:461 1254 F FATAL 
ccd0.log:01-28 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat test_mcd.log 
mcd0.log:01-29 09:33:18:461 1254 F NORMAL
mcd0.log:01-29 09:33:18:461 1254 F FATAL 
mcd0.log:01-29 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
```

and I want to generate the following backup files

```
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat test_ccd.log.txt
ccd0.log:01-28 09:33:18:461 1254 F FATAL 
ccd0.log:01-28 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat test_mcd.log.txt
mcd0.log:01-29 09:33:18:461 1254 F FATAL 
mcd0.log:01-29 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
```

I'd tried the following commands to achieve that purpose but neither of them are succeed, please anybody help to correct anything I did wrong?

```
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.2 (Final)

# this commands hangs for ever
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -E "ALARM|FATA:" 1>>"$0.txt"' {} \;

# this commands reports the error and the output was missed up
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -R -E "ALARM|FATA:" 1>>"$0.txt"' {} \;
grep: input file ‘test_mcd.log.txt’ is also the output
grep: input file ‘test_ccd.log.txt’ is also the output

# the output for each file is not correct
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat test_mcd.log.txt
test_mcd.log:mcd0.log:01-29 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
test_ccd.log:ccd0.log:01-28 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
[root@TENCENT64 /tmp/test]# cat test_ccd.log.txt
test_mcd.log:mcd0.log:01-29 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
test_ccd.log:ccd0.log:01-28 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
test_mcd.log.txt:test_mcd.log:mcd0.log:01-29 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
test_mcd.log.txt:test_ccd.log:ccd0.log:01-28 09:34:30:827 1254 E ALARM
```

Also thing get complicated when I tried to use the following codes to persist the backed alarms to another location, I have a NFS share to store the backup alarms and each of them are stored separately into its folder (named with IP address) on the share, below is my command

```
# create the backed folder on the NFS share, like /data/backup/1.1.1.1/alarm_history
ip=`hostname -I|awk '{print $1}'` && mkdir -p /data/backup/${ip}/alarm_history

# iterate through /data/backup/1.1.1.1 to find all the alarms and persist into /data/backup/1.1.1.1/alarm_history, /data/backup is a shared base and 1.1.1.1 is mounted on the current server
ip=`hostname -I|awk '{print $1}'` && find /data/backup/${ip} -name '*.log' -type f -exec sh -c '
    grep -E "ALARM|FATAL" "$1" >> "/data/backup/${ip}/alarm_history/$1.alarm" && sort -o "/data/backup/${ip}/alarm_history/$1.alarm" -u "/data/backup/${ip}/alarm_history/$1.alarm"
' 'find-sh' {} \;
```

it yield two erros:

```
find-sh: line 1: /data/backup//alarm_history//data/backup/11.62.17.249/manager/manager_mcd0.log.alarm: No such file or directory
find-sh: line 1: /data/backup//alarm_history//data/backup/11.62.17.249/manager/manager_mcd0_stat.log.alarm: No such file or directory
```

they are two issue,
1, the ${ip} passed into the command "find" can not be recongized within the grep.
2. $1.alarm, the $1 is the absoulte pass in the grep, how can I get the basename of it?

Answer (score 6):

The argument to `grep` is missing and `:` should be an `L` to get the expected result, thus

```
grep -E "ALARM|FATA:" 1>> "$0.txt"
```

should be

```
grep -E "ALARM|FATAL" "$0" > "$0.txt"
```

(or use `>>` or `1>>` if you want to append the result to an existing file)

Since `$0` should be the command name and positional parameters start with `$1`, you could add a name and pass the result as `$1` to the script:

```
find . -name '*.log' -type f -exec sh -c '
    grep -E "ALARM|FATAL" "$1" > "$1.txt"
' 'find-sh' {} \;
```

Or loop the results using as few `sh` invocations as possible with `{} +`:

```
find . -name '*.log' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do
        grep -E "ALARM|FATAL" "$file" > "${file}.txt"
    done
' 'find-sh' {} +
```

---

**Edit:**

I added a variable for the target directory which is passed as first argument to the script.
To be able to sort the resulting logfile, I used a temporary file.

```
ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{ print $1 }')
targetdir="/data/backup/$ip/alarm_history"
mkdir -p "$targetdir"

find "/data/backup/$ip" -name '*.log' -type f -exec sh -c '
    targetdir=$1; shift

    for file; do
            # extract the log filename from the path, append ".alarm", prepend directory
            targetfile=${targetdir}/${file##*/}.alarm

            grep -E "ALARM|FATAL" "$file" >> "$targetfile" \
                && mv "$targetfile" "${targetfile}.tmp" \
                && sort -o "$targetfile" -u "${targetfile}.tmp" \
                && rm "${targetfile}.tmp"
    done
' 'find-sh' "$targetdir" {} +
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy, this work perfectly, one more question, what is find-sh here? is it a subroutine name? what if I remove it?

Comment: It's how I named the `sh`-scripts, this is `$0` inside the script and the first argument passed to the script with option `-c`. The remaining arguments are the ones from `find`. You can choose any name or an empty String. If you removed it in the first script, the first argument would be `$0` and not `$1`. In the second script the first `find` result would be missing in the loop (`for file; do` is a shortcut for `for file in "$@"; do` where the first positional parameter is `$1`).

Answer (score 3):

This may be easier as a `for` loop

eg

```
for file in *.log
do
  grep -E -- "ALARM|FATAL" "$file" > "$file.txt"
done
```